# customize radio button using css

Tags: css, radio-button

I've been trying to customize the default radio button to look something like on/off button.
I've already created one using 2 images (using javascript) for an on and off state, but there's no animation for transition between the two states.

Is there a way to achieve this using pure css(+ animation)?

I need buttons like these-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go you can also do this with checkbox

```css
#mc, #mc2, #mc3 {
  display: none;
}
.switch {
  background: gray;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}
.switch:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
.switch:after {
  content: "";
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: ease-out 0.5s;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:after,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after{
  left: calc(100% - 19px);
  background: lightgreen;
  }
```

```html
<p>Radio</p>
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="Switch" />
<label class="switch" for="mc"></label>

<input type="radio" id="mc2" name="Switch" />
<label class="switch" for="mc2"></label>
<p>Checkbox</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="mc3" name="Switch" />
<label class="switch" for="mc3"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get transition between the two state (on/off), style the **:checked** pseudo class.

The **:checked** pseudo class matches every checked <input> element (radio, checkbox and option).

```css
/* The container */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .5em;
  width: 46px;
  height: 24px;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio */
.switch input[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Create a custom switch */
.switch .slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #daa2e6;
  transition: .2s;
}

/* Create the indicator/dot */
.switch .slider::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #bababa;
  transition: .2s;
}

/* When the switch is checked, add a blue background */
.switch input[type=radio]:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #007bff;
}

/* When the switch is checked, change position of the indicator/dot */
.switch input[type=radio]:checked + .slider::before {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(18px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(18px);
  transform: translateX(18px);
}

/* When the switch gets focus, add a shadow */
.switch input[type=radio]:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
  border-color: #80bdff;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" name="country">
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label> United States
</p>

<p>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" name="country">
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label> Canada
</p>

<p>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" name="country" checked>
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label> United Kingdom
</p>

<p>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" name="country">
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label> India
</p>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in your answer and avoid posting code only answers.